# How to update [name] in css-loader?

Tags: webpack, sass

My sass filenames are like `Component.module.scss`. When I add sass modules I hope to see something like `Component__button_jP9v7`. However the result is `Component-module__button_jP9v7`. My webpack configuration is like below (only giving the relevant part):

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: {
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
          },
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any possible way to change `[name]` so that I can remove `-module` part from the class name?